# When I use mplot3D, why get error: NameError: name 'plot_trisurf' is not defined

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to use mplot3D to draw some 3D pictures:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
...
plot_trisurf(X, Y, Z1)
```

Then my computer will tell me that

```
NameError: name 'plot_trisurf' is not defined
```

Why this happen?  I thought I have imported it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`plot_trisurf`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#tri-surface-plots) is a method from the `Axes3D` class. In python, in order to call a class method, you usually need to provide the class or an instance of it.

In this case the class instance would be your axes object. This is usually called `ax`. The correct call would therefore be (as seen on the [matplotlib trisurf example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/trisurf3d_demo.html)):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
...
ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z)
plt.show()
```